# Como correguir mi el problema Http response code: 413 en AWS lambda?

Tags: nodejs, aws, amazon-s3, serverless

Tengo este problema al momento de enviar información de mi AWS Lambda, cual seria la solucion.

Tengo mi proyecto donde tengo imagenes privadas, el usuario se autentica por medio de un token y el backend le responde con la información de la imagen de la siguiente forma:

```
module.exports.handle = async (event) => {
    try {
        const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            authenticationServerless(event).then(async retD => { //Comprueba al autenticación del usuario
                const { imgFolder, key } = event.pathParameters
                try {
                    // Obtener la imagen
                    const result = await controll.getImage(`private/${imgFolder}/${decodeURI(key)}`)
                    //---------------------------------
                    // - Imagen a enviar ----
                    result.Body.transformToByteArray().then(respo => {
                        resolve({
                            headers: {
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                            },
                            statusCode: 200,
                            isBase64Encoded: true,
                            body: Buffer.from(respo, 'binary').toString('base64')
                        })
                    })
                    //---------------------------------
                } catch (e) {
                    reject({
                        statusCode: 500,
                        body: JSON.stringify({ message: e.stack, path: `private/${imgFolder}/${key}` })
                    })
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                reject(err)
            })
        })
        return result
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

Ahora mi problema surge porque tengo imagenes que on mayores de 3.MB, al momenot que quiero enviar una imagen mayora 3.MB me aparece:

```
LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 413.
```

Por lo que no se si hay alguna forma de enviar archivos mas grandes o darle mas recursos a lambda o si se puede configurar

Estoy usando `Serverless 2` y `nodejs 14` tambien `@aws-sdk/client-s3:3.267`

Answer (score 1):

Para manejar imágenes grandes en AWS Lambda, lo más práctico sería usar URLs presignadas de Amazon S3. Básicamente, en lugar de intentar enviar la imagen completa a través de Lambda (lo cual claramente está causando problemas debido a los límites de tamaño), lo que haces es subir la imagen a un bucket de S3. Luego, generas una URL presignada para esa imagen y la envías en tu respuesta de Lambda.

Con esta URL presignada, el usuario podrá acceder directamente a la imagen en S3. Es una manera súper eficiente de manejar archivos grandes, ya que evitas los límites de tamaño de Lambda y reduces la carga en tu función. Además, el proceso de configuración de las URLs presignadas no es complicado.

Comment: Usaba eso al principio, pero queria que llevara un token de authenticación, entonces, podri agregarlo a mi s3? en lugar de una url presignadas podria usar un token de autenticación?

Comment: @TDPerez lo que puedes hacer es poner un tiempo suficientemente pequeño (10 minutos quizás) a las url presigned como para no tener que preocuparte del token. De hecho, si la imagen está pensada para visualizarse en el momento, con un presigned de 1 o 2 minutos de vida máxima te debería servir. Con esos plazos tan cortos nadie va a poder descargarse una imagen si no es a través del api de tu servicio

Comment: Lo voy aplicarlo y ver como me funciona